# How do I solve the problem of NULL SID Logon when triggering Chromium Browser and performing web automation with node.js Puppeteer module?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to do some website automation (e.g.: form-filling and submission) by using node.js puppeteer module. However, I encounter a problem that may lead to locking of my local user account with administrator priviledge. From the event viewer, NULL SID Logon (event ID) 4625 takes place and the local account is locked after 5 times of such a logon. The cause of account locking after 5 times of failure is group policy set by the company I work for.

My questions are, why is there a NULL SID logon attempt when triggering Chromium Browser and performing web automation with puppeteer? and how do I solve the problem by making no NULL SID logon attempt when performing web automation?

Information of the problem encountered is as follows:

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 2019 64-bit (Windows version 1809)

Version of node.js: 14.16.1 LTS Version

Chromium Version: 91.00.4469.0 (64-bit)

Source Code of my testing program:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function main() {
    while (true) {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, defaultViewport: null , args:['--start-maximized', '--ignore-certificate-errors']});
        const pages = await browser.pages();
        const page = pages[0];
        await page.goto('http://www.google.com.hk', {waitUntil: "networkidle0"});
        await page.waitForTimeout(120000);
        await browser.close();
        await sleep(3000);
    }
}

// Function Use: Make the program sleep for milliseconds
// Function Input: milliseconds
async function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve,ms));
}


main();
```

I run the program with a bat file with the following content:

```
D:
cd "D:\Program Files\Test\JSScript"
node BrowserTest.js
exit
```

After running the program, an event (ID: 4625) is logged in event viewer:

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        Workstation\admin1
    Account Name:       admin1
    Account Domain:     Workstation
    Logon ID:       0x1BE6964

Logon Type:         2

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       admin1
    Account Domain:     Workstation

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xC000006D
    Sub Status:     0xC000006A

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x2d90
    Caller Process Name:    D:\Program Files\Test\JSScript\node_modules\puppeteer\.local-chromium\win64-869685\chrome-win\chrome.exe

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   Workstation
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      Advapi  
    Authentication Package: Negotiate
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0

This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.

The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.

The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
    - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
    - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
    - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.
```

After 5 times of the occurrence of the above event, another event (ID: 4740) is logged in the event viewer:

```
A user account was locked out.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       Workstation$
    Account Domain:     MyCompanyDomain
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Account That Was Locked Out:
    Security ID:        Workstation\admin1
    Account Name:       admin1

Additional Information:
    Caller Computer Name:   Workstation
```

I am new here and if I miss anything, I will provide further information.